# Synonyms for outsourcing

Tags: word-request

We are a web developer company, and we rebranded our website recently. When we made a proofreading, the guy said `outsourcing` has a kind of negative meaning in the US. What other words can we use that has the meaning of outsourcing in the context of `Outsourced project development`.

Comment: Please show us your homework!

Comment: By the way, don't associate your company with 'outsourcing'. If that American holds a grudge, call yourself an 'offshore development company'!

Comment: Outsourcing I don't think is as negative as offshore @MaulikV. There are some people in the US that get upset that work is being sent to other countries, which gives it the negative connotation. Outsourcing just means to not do the work within your own company and doesn't necessarily mean to send the work to another country. Offshore definitely means to send the work to another country. Also, offshore accounts are where rich people hide their money to avoid taxes :)

Comment: @MaulikV I am not native speaker, thats why I am asking. I cant do my homework on this. Ofc I can check how other companies tackle this but I wont get the "underlying cultural meaning" of the words they use.

Comment: In short, any synonym or euphemism you end up using will have the same connotations, both positive (low-cost) and negative (low-quality) as the original *outsourcing* does, because that's the perception of the *activity itself* (a rose by any other name, euphemism treadmill, etc).

Comment: https://www.powerthesaurus.org/outsourcing

Comment: *outsourcing* also has a negative connotation in that a company usually does not have complete control over their operations. This can allow the possibility of some problem happening. Unless there is a specific reason or required disclosure, I would not mention it to customers (as @ColleenV pointed out).

Comment: Outsourcing is outsourcing. And it is a type of subcontracting. That said, I feel that this question is as problematic as the recent question on META re "colored". Are we here to providing free editing to make things sound hunky-dorey? After all, it is editing, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason ***outsourcing*** has negative connotations is because it's generally used in contexts where the current (local) workforce are losing their jobs (usually, to cheaper workers in another country).

You might perhaps avoid (or at least *reduce*) those connotations with [***subcontracting.***](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/subcontracting.html)

> *A business practice where main contractor hires additional individuals or companies called **subcontractors** to help complete a project. The main contractor is still in charge and must oversee hires to ensure project is executed and completed as specified in contract.*

Comment: Or just avoid it all together. What does an enterprise web development company do other than provide web development services to other businesses? Outsourcing/offshore/subcontracting might not be necessary at all. For example, http://www.iflexion.com/ just mentions how many projects in how many countries, and how many clients and what types they have.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when working for a large UK bank.  In the end, we used the phrase "Distributed development".  For a while, I worked as part of an "Internationally based software testing department", as well.  Either of those would be an acceptable alternative.